# How do I collapse a table row in Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 2.3.2 in my app and I need to completely hide a row using the collapse plugin.  Below is an example:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Collapse test</title>
            <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <tr>
                <td>
                  <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseme">
                    Click to expand
                  </button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td><div class="collapse out" id="collapseme">Should be collapsed</div></td></tr>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

This will correctly show and hide the contents of the row, but the collapsed row is still visible.  See this screenshot:

[image: Collapsed row still visible]

The grey line in the screenshot shows the extra row.  What can I do to completely remove this row from view?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You are using collapse on the div inside of your table row (tr). So when you collapse the div, the row is still there. You need to change it to where your id and class are on the tr instead of the div.

Change this:

```
<tr><td><div class="collapse out" id="collapseme">Should be collapsed</div></td></tr>
```

to this:

```
<tr class="collapse out" id="collapseme"><td><div>Should be collapsed</div></td></tr>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KnuU6/21/

EDIT: If you are unable to upgrade to 3.0.0, I found a JQuery workaround in 2.3.2:

Remove your data-toggle and data-target and add this JQuery to your button.

```
$(".btn").click(function() {
    if($("#collapseme").hasClass("out")) {
        $("#collapseme").addClass("in");
        $("#collapseme").removeClass("out");
    } else {
        $("#collapseme").addClass("out");
        $("#collapseme").removeClass("in");
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KnuU6/25/

Comment: Thanks, Chad.  Works in fiddle, but not locally because I am using 2.3.2. I had tried this before (in 2.3.2) and it was broken.  I guess the real answer is to upgrade to 3.0.0.  Sigh...not an easy upgrade since there are quite a few changes and no migration guide AFAICT.

Comment: That was my mistake. I threw my version of bootstrap (3.0.0) into my fiddle and didn't think that something like this would be broken on the older version. I hope that it helps and you get it working!

Comment: I added onto my answer and supplied a 2.3.2 workaround if you can't get your upgrade working.

Comment: In the fiddle, it's still using 3.0.0 CSS, so the 2.3.2 workaround doesn't help if you're using the whole 2.3.2 package. The CSS for .collapse is different in 2.3.2.

Comment: How would this work if you wanted to expand/collapse multiple rows. e.g. you have a parent row, which when clicked displays 3 child rows on click.

Comment: Any way to do this on multiple rows with one click?

Comment: @Maelish You can use a class on each row instead of one ID on a single row. Is this something like what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/KnuU6/1165/

Comment: Good answer @Tricky12

Answer (score 7):

I just came up with the same problem since we still use bootstrap 2.3.2.

My solution for this: http://jsfiddle.net/KnuU6/281/

css:

```
.myCollapse {
    display: none;
}
.myCollapse.in {
    display: block;
}
```

javascript:

```
 $("[data-toggle=myCollapse]").click(function( ev ) {
   ev.preventDefault();
   var target;
   if (this.hasAttribute('data-target')) {
 target = $(this.getAttribute('data-target'));
   } else {
 target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
   };
   target.toggleClass("in");
 });
```

html:

```
<table>
  <tr><td><a href="#demo" data-toggle="myCollapse">Click me to toggle next row</a></td></tr>
  <tr class="collapse" id="#demo"><td>You can collapse and expand me.</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: In my case, the hidden table row spanned multiple columns, so I had to change to `display: table-row` instead of just `block`.

Comment: You sir deserve more upvotes, this was the answer. Thank you. BTW I also had to use table-row in the display, just as the comment before this one.

Comment: This indeed works like a charm. My Question now is, how can I do this trick over multiple rows? It seems that this only works with one.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to set the table cell padding to zero. Here's a jsfiddle (using Bootstrap 2.3.2) with your code slightly modified:

http://jsfiddle.net/marciowerner/fhjgn7b5/4/

The javascript is optional and only needed if you want to use a cell padding other than zero.

```js
$('.collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(this).parent().removeClass("zeroPadding");
});

$('.collapse').on('hide.bs.collapse', function() {
  $(this).parent().addClass("zeroPadding");
});
```

```css
.zeroPadding {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseme">Click to expand</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="zeroPadding">
        <div class="collapse out" id="collapseme">Should be collapsed</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Bootstrap are you using? I was perplexed that I could get @Chad's solution to work in jsfiddle, but not locally. So, I checked the version of Bootstrap used by jsfiddle, and it's using a 3.0.0-rc1 release, while the default download on getbootstrap.com is version 2.3.2.

In 2.3.2 the `collapse` class wasn't getting replaced by the `in` class. The `in` class was simply getting appended when the button was clicked. In version 3.0.0-rc1, the `collapse` class correctly is removed, and the `<tr>` collapses.

Use @Chad's solution for the html, and try using these links for referencing Bootstrap:

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah, it's 2.3.2 as I mention in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without any JavaScript involved

*(Using accepted answer)*

HTML

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <tr>
        <td><button class="btn" data-target="#collapseme" data-toggle="collapse" type="button">Click to expand</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="nopadding">
            <div class="collapse" id="collapseme">
                <div class="content">
                    Show me collapsed
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
.nopadding {
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.content {
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

problem is that the collapse item (div) is nested in the table elements. The div is hidden, the tr and td of the table are still visible and some css-styles are applied to them (border and padding). 
Why are you using tables? Is there a reason for? When you dont´t have to use them, dont´use them :-)

Comment: @chad ´s solution seems god :-)

Comment: take the 3er version or avoid the tables :-) With jquery you can monitor the change or click event or smtg else and then you easily can change the css.