# How to collapse rows(tr) on page Load in ASP.net via java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I need help in collapsing the table rows which is created dynamically from user control(`.ascx`). This should be collapsed on page load and should be expanded on click.

```
<tr class="DocModuleTitleBg">
<td>
<asp:Label ID="lblMdTitle" runat="server" CssClass="DocModuleTitle"</asp:Label></td>
<td>
<telerik:RadMenu Style="float: right" ID="EditMenu" runat="server" Skin="Transparent">
</telerik:RadMenu>
</td>
</tr><tr class="DocModuleTitleBg">
<td>
<asp:Label ID="lblMdTitle" runat="server" CssClass="DocModuleTitle"</asp:Label></td>
<td>
<telerik:RadMenu Style="float: right" ID="EditMenu" runat="server" Skin="Transparent">
</telerik:RadMenu>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: How can you click something that's collapsed? Also, seeing your code and your attempt to achieve this will save you from a lot of downvotes

Comment: Actually, i am new to this and  this is a module which is created dynamically by the help of row. On page load all the modules are expanded. but i want that to be collapsed on page load and on click want that to be expanded one by one

Comment: i want something like this [link](http://www.newschool.edu/ajax/CollapsiblePanel/CollapsiblePanel.aspx)

Comment: I replaced your inline code markers (`\``) with a code block. The easiest way to format a code block on SO is to paste your code, then select it and press Ctrl+K or click the `{}` button. This indents the whole block by an additional four spaces, instructing Stack Overflow to format it as code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something along the following lines. It is by no means good but posting more of your initial code will help answerers build upon what you already have rather than having to write it from scratch.

```js
$('#lblMdTitle').on('click', function(){
  $('#EditMenu').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
#EditMenu{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr class="DocModuleTitleBg">
  <td>
    <Label ID="lblMdTitle" runat="server" CssClass="DocModuleTitle">Title</Label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div ID="EditMenu" runat="server" Skin="Transparent">
      Content
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18496059/1892310) might be helpful for you if you are using Bootstrap.

Please go through it.