# Bootstrap-table make expandable rows

Tags: java, html, twitter-bootstrap, velocity, bootstrap-table

I have a Java endpoint which is using velocity and returns a html page with table, I am using `bootstrap` v3.3.7 and `bootstrap-table` v1.12.1,

This page mostly contains a table, some rows which should expanded and show another table in the expended view. Currently its done via `hiddenRow` and `collapse`:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/master/src/bootstrap-table.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.12.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered" style="border-collapse:collapse;" data-toggle="table" data-pagination="true" data-search="true" data-show-pagination-switch="true">

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Column1</th>
        <th>Column2</th>
        <th>Column3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsedRow1" class="accordion-toggle">
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="12" class="hiddenRow">
          <div class="accordion-body collapse container-fluid" id="collapsedRow1">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Inner Table Column1</th>
                  <th>Inner Table Column2</th>
                  <th>Inner Table Column3</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>1</td>
                  <td>2</td>
                  <td>3</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Similar solution here: 
https://www.bootply.com/fdTMNTiLis

and here:
[How do I collapse a table row in Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495653/how-do-i-collapse-a-table-row-in-bootstrap?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

So as the result I have a table with expandable structure, but inner tables are present in additional rows and not tied to their "parent" rows. As the result when sorting by some column, these hidden rows are somewhere in the end of the table, when the rows which expand them are in totally different place, same problem is with pagination, because when you choose 10 rows per page it actually displays 5 rows + 5 hidden rows, and with search, as it shows only rows which contains pattern you searched for, but not the row which is expanded by this row.

Is there any other approach which resolves at least some of these problems? or maybe there is a way to tie this in pair of rows?