# How to Expand/Collapse Dynamic table row data

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I'm getting some data from servlet and displaying it in Jsp as a table using iterations.Now I want to expand/collapse each row individually based on row data item.
I'm getting those data using ajax cal,but representing is the problem

```
    </script>
<script type= "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('tr.parent').css("cursor","pointer")
        .attr("title","click to expand/collapse")
        .click(function(){
            $(this).siblings('.child-'+this.id).toggle();
        });
        $('tr[@class^=child-]').hide.children('td');
    });
</script>

        <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-striped" >
            <tr>
            <th>Request ID</th>
            <th>User ID</th>
            <th>Login URL</th>
            <th>Reason</th>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${Env}" var="col">
        <tr class="parent" id="env">
            <td><a class="value" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#details" href="./envDetails?envId=${col.environmentid }"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-collapse-down"></span>${col.environmentid }</a></td>
            <td>${col.userid }</td>
            <td>${col.loginURL }</td>
            <td>${col.reason }</td>
        </tr>
    <tr id="details" class="child-env" style="display: table-row;">
            <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Script Name</th>
                <th>Module</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
            </table>
         </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
```

when ever expand the row it has to show like below

```
    <tr>
        <th>Script Name</th>
        <th>Module</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I collapse a table row in Bootstrap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495653/how-do-i-collapse-a-table-row-in-bootstrap)

Comment: Thank you for giving response, this one  works for if table has fixed rows, in my case table has rows through looping for that one it is not working, if I click on one row all rows will be expanding, actually it has to expand particular row only.

Comment: @GPADMAVATHI Where's the JavaScript?

Comment: </script>
<script type= "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('tr.parent').css("cursor","pointer")
        .attr("title","click to expand/collapse")
        .click(function(){
            $(this).siblings('.child-'+this.id).toggle();
        });
        $('tr[@class^=child-]').hide.children('td');
    });
</script>